# Adding joins and selects to a linq-to-sql lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have the following three generated classes that I am trying to write a linq-to-sql query against to dynamically add joins based on settings:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class UserEmail
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class UserPhone
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

This is what would be ideal to execute against the database, but I would be fine with retrieving all columns from the joined tables:

```
// If includeEmail and includePhone are both true.
SELECT  u.*, ue.Address, up.PhoneNumber
FROM    users u
JOIN    user_email ue ON u.user_id = ue.user_id
JOIN    user_phone up ON u.user_id = up.user_id

// If includeEmail and includePhone are both false.
SELECT  u.*
FROM    users u
```

And here is the code I am working with:

```
// Base query
var queryableUsers = m_context.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == 1).Select(u => u);

// Join to other tables based on settings
if (includeEmail)
{
    Expression<Func<UserEmails, UserEmails>> emailSelector = (ue => ue.Address);
    queryableUsers = queryableUsers.Join(m_context.UserEmails, u => u.UserId, ue => ue.UserId).Select(emailSelector);

}
if (includePhone)
{
    Expression<Func<UserPhones, UserPhones>> phoneSelector = (up => up.PhoneNumber);
    queryableUsers = queryableUsers.Join(m_context.UserPhones, u => u.UserId, up => up.UserId).Select(phoneSelector);

}

// Execute query
var results = queryableUsers.ToList();
```

Comment: Your results supposed to be `List<User>`. But `User` do not have properties for mail and phone. So, you still returning only data from user. Select will not change

Comment: Right, I know my code is not correct, just trying to give you an idea of what I am trying to do. Basically I am trying to return the following object, but don't know how to reference my joins that were added without doing subqueries in the select:
new { 
                    User = u,
                    Address = u.UserEmailList.Where(ue => ue.UserId == u.User_id).Select(ue => ue.Address).FirstOrDefault(),
                    PhoneNumber = u.UserPhoneList.Where(up => up.UserId == u.UserId).Select(up => up.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault()
                    }

Answer (score 0):

The problem you'll face is that you're trying to change the type of `queryableUsers`. Essentially you're attempting:

```
IQueryable<User> queryableUsers = originalQuery;

if(includeEmail)
    queryableUsers = IQueryable<UserEmails>;
if(includePhone)
    queryableUsers = IQueryable<UserPhones>;
```

I don't know your exact situation, but you likely don't need to even decide when to include one or another (this is probably a very fast query, in which case clarity and ease of use is preferred) and just query like so:

```
var userData = (from u in m_context.Users
                where u.UserId == 1
                select new
                {
                    User = u,
                    EmailAddress = u.UserEmail.Address,
                    PhoneNumber = u.UserPhone.PhoneNumber
                }).ToList();
```

Or, if you want to use the entities directly, you can use [DataLoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith.aspx) to eagerly load the related entities when necessary:

```
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();

if(includeEmail)
    options.LoadWith<User>(u => u.UserEmail);

m_context.LoadOptions = options;

var userData = m_context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == 1)
                              .ToList();

foreach(var user in userData)
{
    // If includeEmail == true, then this will not trigger another db call
    // If includeEmail == false, then the UserEmail property will be lazily
    // loaded and another db call will be made for every iteration of this
    // loop (very bad).
    Console.WriteLine(user.UserEmail.Address);
}
```